# Which loop to use?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, char

I want the user to input the number of cups and my program will do the calculates for them for subtotal, tax, and total. Then I want the program to ask if they want to order more lemonade. If they put 'y', it will let them add, if they put 'n', it will stop. Which loop(While, do, for) should I use?

Here is what I have so far:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int NumCups,count=0;
    float SubTot, Tot = 0, Tax;
    char more;
    printf("Enter the number of cups:");
    scanf("%d", &NumCups);
    SubTot = NumCups*1.29;
    Tax = SubTot*0.0825;
    Tot = SubTot + Tax;

    printf("Subtotal:%0.2f\nTax:%0.2f\nTotal:%0.2f\n", SubTot, Tax, Tot);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Thank you.\nWould you like to order more lemonade?\n");
    scanf("%c", &more);
    while(more!='y')
    {
        SubTot += SubTot;
        Tax +=Tax;
        Tot+=Tot;
        printf("Enter the number of cups:");
        scanf("%d", &NumCups);
        printf("Subtotal:%0.2f\nTax:%0.2f\nTotal:%0.2f\n", SubTot, Tax, Tot);
    }
        system("pause");
    }
```

Comment: Where did you got stuck? What's not working as expected with your program?

Comment: @cristik I want the loop to keep asking if i want to order more. But after it asks me the first time, it stops.

Comment: Any of those loop choices can be coerced into doing what you want; why don't you try one and ask a more specific question if you have problems?

Comment: @carlNorum I've tried the while loop, but I don't know how to write a code for it to do what I want.

Comment: All loop types can accomplish this task. I'd say it's really more personal preference. Use whatever seems like a more readable syntax to you.

Comment: @dman2306 how would I go about it with a while loop?

Comment: Why don't you post what you tried and someone can help you? The code above doesn't even include a loop. To be honest, your post to me looks like an assignment, and while I'm happy to help, I want to help, not do it for you so you can learn. If you post your attempt, myself, or someone else can help find your flaw and correct it. Right now your code doesn't even attempt a loop.

Comment: @dman2306 here is what I tried.

Comment: I have to look more closely but right off the bat remove the ; after the while(). That means, essentially "do nothing" as it means the ; is the part inside the while, not the {}

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: It's nice to add the [tag:c] tag so people know what language you're using.

Comment: main returning void and taking int ,brrrr

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a C compiler handy so I can't guarantee it is 100% correct but something like this seems like what you want. What I did here was ask the user before the loop starts. Then the loop runs if they said yes. At the end of the loop, it will ask them again. If they say no, it will break. If they say yes, it loops until they say no. Like I said, don't have a C compiler handy, so it might need minor changes but it should get you on the right track. My guess looking at it is all the subtotal calculation stuff is wrong here since nothing in the loop is using NumCups, but I think this at least answers the question of how to use a loop.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    int NumCups,count=0;
    float SubTot, Tot = 0, Tax;
    char more='y';
    printf("Enter the number of cups:");
    scanf("%d", &NumCups);
    SubTot = NumCups*1.29;
    Tax = SubTot*0.0825;
    Tot = SubTot + Tax;

    printf("Subtotal:%0.2f\nTax:%0.2f\nTotal:%0.2f\n", SubTot, Tax, Tot);
    fflush(stdin);
        printf("Thank you.\nWould you like to order more lemonade?\n");
        scanf("%c", &more);

    while(more=='y')
    {

        SubTot += SubTot;
        Tax +=Tax;
        Tot+=Tot;
        printf("Enter the number of cups:");
        scanf("%d", &NumCups);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Thank you.\nWould you like to order more lemonade?\n");
        scanf("%c", &more);
    }
        system("pause");
    }
```